# NodeJs not attatching both filter properties to url params

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, query-string

I am trying to do a get request and pass a couple of url params into the request but for some reason the request seems to be only adding one of the two url params with the same name.

my code is:

```
  async function getOrderByDate(data) {
   const options = {
    method: 'get',
    url: config.cloverApiUrl +'/v3/merchants/'+data.merchant_id
      +'/orders',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + data.token,
      ContentType: 'application/json'
    },
    qs: {
      filter: `clientCreatedTime>` +data.minDate,
      filter: `clientCreatedTime<` +data.maxDate,
      expand: 'lineItems',
      limit: 1000
    }
  };
  console.log('here ' +JSON.stringify(options.qs));
  const response = request(options);
}
```

The issue is when I log the query parameters before the request I get:

```
 here {"filter":"clientCreatedTime<1613624400000","expand":"lineItems","limit":1000}
```

I don't know why it only added all url params including one clientCreatedTime filter but not the other. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Object properties are unique, there can only be one `filter`.

Comment: But in the documentation for clover they say to pass multiple filters for multiple filtering and it works fine in postman as well. Is there any way around this? Since a duplicate property on an object is not allowed, what is an alternative way to pass multiple same url params into the request?

Comment: Could you link the documentation?

Comment: The documentation for clover filter is: https://docs.clover.com/docs/applying-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use an array:

```
      filter: [`clientCreatedTime>` +data.minDate, `clientCreatedTime<` +data.maxDate],
```

And you'll have to set `qsStringifyOptions` to `{ indices: false }`:

```
   const options = {
    method: 'get',
    url: config.cloverApiUrl +'/v3/merchants/'+data.merchant_id
      +'/orders',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + data.token,
      ContentType: 'application/json'
    },
    qs: {
      filter: [`clientCreatedTime>` +data.minDate, `clientCreatedTime<` +data.maxDate],
      expand: 'lineItems',
      limit: 1000
    },
    qsStringifyOptions: { indices: false }
  };
```

Also, `request` is deprecated. So you'd want to find out a way to do with `fetch` most likely. Several packages exist for this like `node-fetch`, `whatwg-fetch`, `isomorphic-fetch`.

And as a second reminder, if it's the `request` library, you'd need to use either the callback or treat it as a stream. If it's `request-promise`, that would get you a promise but you do need to `await` it to get the response. That `async` function has no return value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works like a charm. I am aware of the deprecated request and was planning on changing the api's to use the new packages. Currently I am using request-promise, which would you recommend as  the best alternative to request-promise that would be easy to switch over too?

Comment: I use `node-fetch`. It mimics browsers fetch API. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)